# My text moves when my transition happens and my button height is opposite

Tags: html, css

I want to not make my text move when the transition happens. And my one button moves upwards while the other three move downwards. I want to make them all move downwards. These are the problems. Please solve me these issues.
Three buttons move downwards while the one move upwards.
[The button problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQwb6.png)
and the text is bugged too. Please run this code and help me by solving the problems.
I have tried making the position: absolute but its not working.
Thanks in advance!
I tried to make a page, when it is all moving.

```css
body {
  background-image: url("background.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.hello {
  position: relative;
  color: black;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  text-align: center;
}

.sadness {
  position: relative;
  color: grey;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  text-align: center;
  top: -250px;
}

.line {
  position: relative;
  width: 170px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: black;
  left: 580px;
  top: 140px;
}

.project {
  position: relative;
  color: grey;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  text-align: center;
  top: -270px;
}

.best {
  position: relative;
  color: grey;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  text-align: center;
  top: -330px;
}

.line2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 170px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: black;
  left: 580px;
  top: 280px;
}

.button {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
  left: 490px;
  top: 200px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border-top: 3px;
  border-left: 3px;
  border-right: 3px;
  border-bottom: 3px;
  border-color: grey;
  border-style: solid;
  transition: all 400ms;
}

.button:hover {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
  height: 70px;
  border-color: aqua;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.button2 {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 15px;
  left: 590px;
  top: 145px;
  border-top: 3px;
  border-left: 3px;
  border-right: 3px;
  border-bottom: 3px;
  border-color: grey;
  border-style: solid;
  transition: 400ms;
}

.button2:hover {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
  height: 70px;
  border-color: aqua;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.button3 {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 15px;
  left: 700px;
  top: 90px;
  border-top: 3px;
  border-left: 3px;
  border-right: 3px;
  border-bottom: 3px;
  border-color: grey;
  border-style: solid;
  transition: 400ms;
}

.button3:hover {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
  height: 70px;
  border-color: aqua;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.button4 {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 15px;
  position: relative;
  left: 800px;
  top: 35px;
  border-top: 3px;
  border-left: 3px;
  border-right: 3px;
  border-bottom: 3px;
  border-color: grey;
  border-style: solid;
  transition: 400ms;
}

.button4:hover {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
  height: 70px;
  border-color: aqua;
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="line2"></div>
  <h1 class="hello" id="hello">hello!</h1>
  <a class="button"></a>
  <a class="button2"></a>
  <a class="button3"></a>
  <a class="button4"></a>
  <p class="sadness">i am sadness7311. i am a developer and a coder.</p>
  <p class="project">i have developed some things like proton addon.</p>
  <p class="best">i always try to do my best!</p>
</body>


</html>
```

My Whole class

Comment: You HTML is a mess. Why would you put the buttons *before* the text if they should appear *after* it? You should fix that and simplify the css. Only then one solution would be to place the buttons inside a position absolute div.  Or maybe it will solve itself if you just do that.

Comment: I'll try that. The fixed the HTML. I am gonna go for the div.